# Использовние JSON в java, android

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Есть json-файл:

```
{
  "easy": [
    {
      "question": "Первый вторник месяца...",
      "tip": "Почему тот мес...",
      "answer": "Поскольку Митя..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Нужно распарсить этот файл и раскидать данные с него в соответствующие `TextView`.

Был бы очень рад, если бы вы расписали всё по шагам (Я новичок и мне трудно понимать монолитный код).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Парсинг:**
*1. Объявить переменные:*

```
String question, tip, answer;
```

*2. Сам парсинг:*

```
String input = "тут ваша json-структура";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject mainObject = parser.parse().getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray easy = mainObject.getAsJsonArray("easy");
for (JsonElement obj : easy) {
    JsonObject userObject = obj.getAsJsonObject();
    question = userObject.get("question");
    tip = userObject.get("tip");
    answer = userObject.get("answer");
    }
}
```

**Получили данные, теперь отображение:**

```
mTextView1.setText(question);
mTextView2.setText(tip);
mTextView3.setText(answer);
```